# OK to drive screws into bottom of vinyl window frame?

Tags: windows

As I was cleaning the windows before winter, I noticed that a lot of the caulking outside has cracked and come away from the window sill. I also noticed that if I push down on the bottom of the frame, it moves up/down about 1/16 of an inch. Then I saw that there are two screw holes in the frame which the previous owner must've put in there. The windows aren't too old, they're typical cheapo department store windows.

The question: is it OK to drive screws into the bottom of the window frame to secure it in place? Will it warp in the summer? This isn't the only window to have such holes in the frame, and we haven't noticed any water damage in the past couple of years.

[image: previous owner screws?]

Comment: The main issue is that vinyl window frames are really a series of individual chambers meant to provide air barriers to help insulate. If you are in a cold climate, the holes have likely compromised some of your energy efficiency. I'd at least caulk the holes shut. As for it moving 1/16 of an inch if you push on it--the easy solution is to stop pushing on it. :)

Comment: And to continue from "stop pushing on it" would be to go outside and peel away the old caulk that has failed and then apply new caulk to bridge the gap and seal it up. If you push / screw too hard on certain parts of the window frame you are likely to open up a crack where the casements fit to the frame.

Comment: those holes look like they're about the size/spacing to hold a window A/C bracket, FWIW.